# JPA CriteriaQuery ManyToMany Predicate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

A many-to-many relationship exists between songs and artists like this:

```
public class Song {
    // ... other fields here
    protected Collection<Artist> artists;
    
    @JoinTable(
        name = "song_artists",
        schema = "playout",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "artist"),
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_song_artists_song"),
        inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_audio_artists_artist")
    )
    @ManyToMany
    public Collection<Artist> getArtists(){
        return artists;
    }

}
```

The artist class is a basic Entity

```
public class Artist {
}
```

Given a Song x, show songs by any of the artists involved in Song x
, A raw SQL query would be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id IN((SELECT song FROM song_artists x WHERE x.artist = ?));
```

Where '?' would be replaced by a comma separated string of artist IDs involved in the song in question

How can the same result be achieved with JPA (using Hibernate specifically)

```
Song song = null; // get desired song
Collection<Artist> artists = song.getArtists();

CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()
CriteriaQuery criteria = builder.createQuery(Song.class);
Root<Song> root = criteria.from(Song.class);

Subquery<Artist> subquery = null; // how to create an appropriate subquery from the join
```

How can we filter the results here (get more songs by any of the artists in "artists" collection)?

Your feedback will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

In case you face something similar, here's what I did:

```
Subquery<Artist> subquery = criteria.subquery(Artist.class);
subquery.from(Artist.class);
Join<Audio, Artist> join = subquery.correlate(root.join("artists", JoinType.LEFT));

subquery.select(builder.nullLiteral(Artist.class));
subquery.where(join.in(value.getArtists()));

criteria.select(root).where(
    builder.and(
        builder.notEqual(root, value), builder.exists(subquery)
    )
);
```